# "no match" and "cannot bind lvalue" errors while overloading `operator<<` with `std::wostream` and `std::string`

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

I've got an error while overloading `std::wostream::operator<<()` for `std::string`. 
Here is the minimal test case illustrating my problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

inline std::wostream &operator<<(std::wostream &os, const std::string &)
{
    return os;
}

class FakeOstream{};

namespace mynamespace {

class FakeClasse1 {
    friend inline FakeOstream &operator<<(FakeOstream &out, const FakeClasse1 &) { 
        return out; 
    }
};

class FakeClasse2 {
    friend inline FakeOstream &operator<<(FakeOstream &out, const FakeClasse2 &)  { 
        return out; 
    }
};

void test()
{
    auto mystring = std::string{u8"mystring"};
    std::wostringstream s;
    s << mystring; // The errors occur here
}

} // namespace mynamespace
```

The code can be compiled and executed here: http://cpp.sh/9emtv

As you can see here, there is an overload for `operator<<` with `std::wostream` 
and `std::string`. The two fake classes are empty apart from the declaration of 
an `operator<<` with `FakeOstream` and themselves. The `test()` function 
instantiate an `std::wostringstream` and feed it a `std::string`. The fake 
fake classes and test function are in a namespace.

This code yields the following error on cpp.sh at the line `s << mystring;`:

```
 In function 'void mynamespace::test()':
25:10: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>&&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/istream:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/sstream:38,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = wchar_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>; _Tp = std::basic_string<char>]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
```

When using directly g++ (version 5.3.0 from MSYS2), a `no match error` is also 
displayed:

```
./tmpbug.cpp: In function 'void mynamespace::test()':
./tmpbug.cpp:25:7: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::wostringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<wchar_t>}' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
     s << mystring;
       ^
In file included from C:/Appli/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0/istream:39:0,
                 from C:/Appli/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0/sstream:38,
                 from ./tmpbug.cpp:2:
C:/Appli/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0/ostream:628:5: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = wchar_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>] <near match>
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
C:/Appli/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0/ostream:628:5: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
./tmpbug.cpp:25:10: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>&&'
     s << mystring;
          ^
In file included from C:/Appli/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0/istream:39:0,
                 from C:/Appli/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0/sstream:38,
                 from ./tmpbug.cpp:2:
```

As far as I know, all the parts of the example are necessary for the errors to 
appear. If I comment out the namespace, the fake classes or just one of the 
`operator<<` in the fake classes, the code compile just fine. Moreover, if I 
just move one of the fake classes or the test function outside of the namespace, 
the code will also compile just fine.

Additionnally, I tried compiling this example on clang 3.7 by using the compiler 
from http://cppreference.com, and the code seems to compile without problems.

Is there a problem with my code or is this a GCC bug ? If this is a GCC bug, is 
there a workaround ?

Comment: If the top section of code compiles then what code produces the errors?

Comment: The code doesn't compile, at least on GCC. The errors occur on the line `s << mystring;`. I've edited the question to add this precision.

Comment: Looks like a name lookup problem to me, but I can't guess what the correct behaviour is. Adding `using ::operator<<;` to `test` is the minimal workaround I've been able to find. (Adding the overload to `std` to enable argument-dependent lookup also makes the problem go away, but I'm not sure how valid that is.)

Comment: Thanks, the `using ::operator<<` seems to work fine :). Nevertheless, I'd like to know why these errors occur, at least to know if I have to file a GCC bug or not.

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed on trunk already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad idea:

```
inline std::wostream &operator<<(std::wostream &os, const std::string &)
```

as you should not overload operators on two types in `std` that do not depend on your own (outside of `std` or build-in) types.  Doing ... doesn't work well.  And, in my opinion, shouldn't be allowed.

Regardless, you can generate the same problem with conforming code by simply creating your own namespace `notstd` and own type `notstd::string`, then in the global root namespace defining

```
inline std::wostream &operator<<(std::wostream &os, const notstd::string &)
{
  return os;
}
```

and get the same symptoms.  So that doesn't matter much.

---

Operators are found first via unqualified name lookup, then via argument dependent lookup.

As we have no `using` statement, unqualified name lookup first looks in the enclosing namespace.  If nothing is found, the namespaces containing it (and eventually the file/global namespace) are then searched.

ADL then augments this with operators found via ADL or Koenig lookup -- it looks in the namespaces of the arguments and their template parameters.

Now, the `friend operator<<` you defined *do* live in the namespace their class contains, *but* they are usually difficult to find.

Somehow your double-declaration of `friend operator<<` is making your code find them, and stop looking into the global namespace for a `<<`.

To me this looks like a bug.  Neither of those "Koenig operators" should be visible to bog-standard unqualified name lookup with types unrelated to the classes they are "contained" in.

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace notstd {
  struct string {};
}

inline void operator<<(std::wostream &os, const notstd::string &){ return; }

class FakeOstream{};

namespace mynamespace {

  class UnusedClass1 {
    friend inline void operator<<(FakeOstream &out, const UnusedClass1 &) { return; }
  };

  class UnusedClass2 {
      // comment this line out and the code compiles:
    friend inline void operator<<(FakeOstream &out, const UnusedClass2 &) { return; }
  };

  void test() {
    auto mystring = notstd::string{};
    std::wostringstream s;
    s << mystring; // The errors occur here
  }

} // namespace mynamespace

int main(){}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/617990600b73ee4e).

@T.C. found what appears to be this bug being fixed:

[test code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2876707b8677e26)

[fix in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/cp/name-lookup.c?r1=226394&r2=227044)

Comment: That's not illegal; you can't put the thing in `namespace std`, so it's silly and pointless, but not illegal.

Comment: @T.C. Last I checked, you cannot overload operators unless the types depend on something outside of `std` and/or built-in types.  Or did I read that defect resolution wrong?

Comment: Which defect resolution are we talking about?

Comment: @T.C. https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2139 -- I did misread.  It doesn't make operators on non-program-defined types illegal.  And the issue is still open.  Mea culpa

Comment: FWIW, [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/cp/name-lookup.c?r1=226394&r2=227044) seems to be the fix, which explains why the code is only broken with two overloads. - Yep, look at this [almost identical](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/testsuite/g%2B%2B.dg/lookup/friend16.C?view=markup&pathrev=227044) test case.

Comment: "Operators are found first via unqualified name lookup, then via argument dependent lookup."  - this applies to all functions called with unqualified-id

Comment: "but they are usually difficult to find." - my understanding is that if the function is only declared as *friend*, then it should be found by ADL but should not be found by non-ADL unqualified lookup  ;  and also that ADL is only considered if the name is not found at all by unqualified lookup.  So the correct behaviour of OP's code is that `::operator<<` should be found, and the existence of that function suppresses the ADL lookup set. Is that correct?

Comment: @M.M "ADL is only considered if the name is not found at all by unqualified lookup" this is wrong.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the operator in the global namespace isn't found because the name lookup somehow stops at one of the friend operator ?

Comment: For your information, it seems that if I put the declaration of the friend operator outside of the unused class without the `friend` keyword, I've got the same error with only one class ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3570c7dec7d3362e)). The first example with the friend operators seems to be fixed in GCC 6, but not the second, is it still valid code or is there another error ?

Comment: @basile if the friend operator is outside, it will be found, and C++ will stop searching for other overloads during unqualified lookup.  ADL will fail to find the root namespace `<<`.  T]No valid overload will be found.  This is one reason why overloading operators on only std types (and primitives) is a bad idea: the right space is the namespace of one of the types, and it is illegal to introduce overloads into `namespace std`.